# How to "merge" page "\Default.aspx" and "\"?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

our site is developed in ASP.NET. We want to block Default.aspx page from Google and other search engines. How can we "close" the Default.aspx page so that it is not accessible?
Or is there another way to solve the problem so that we don't create duplicate content.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't think you need to worry about this but...

You can specify a canonical meta tag

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

So in the head of default.aspx place

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/" />
```

Or you could setup a 301 permanent redirect using url-rewriting to make default.aspx redirect to /

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/), which can be used to stop web crawlers. (At least the nice ones.)